# Arango db not starting

Tags: arangodb, python-arango

I have been using arango db for a month. Its wonderful at almost all the things I want it to do for me. Suddenly I have been having crashes on Linux Mint and I dont know what is the cause. The problems range from missing indexes and memory crashes and I cant seem to find tutorials on  how to exactly put the laid down RocksDb configuaration to stop the crashes. As a result when I check the service status I have got this

````
● arangodb3.service - ArangoDB database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/arangodb3.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2023-06-30 13:08:36 CAT; 2s ago
    Process: 76070 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -g arangodb -o arangodb -d /var/tmp/arangodb3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 76078 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -g arangodb -o arangodb -d /var/run/arangodb3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 76084 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/env chown -R arangodb:arangodb /var/log/arangodb3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 76085 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/env chmod 700 /var/log/arangodb3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 76086 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/env chown -R arangodb:arangodb /var/lib/arangodb3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 76087 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/env chmod 700 /var/lib/arangodb3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 76088 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/env chown -R arangodb:arangodb /var/lib/arangodb3-apps (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 76089 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/env chmod 700 /var/lib/arangodb3-apps (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 76090 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/arangod --uid arangodb --gid arangodb --pid-file /var/run/arangodb3/arangod.pid --temp.path /var/tmp/arangodb3 --log.foreground-t>
   Main PID: 76090 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```
Help me understand on how to fix this issue

The issue proceeds to this

```rangodb3.service - ArangoDB database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/arangodb3.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-06-30 19:12:35 CAT; 1s ago
    Process: 654381 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -g arangodb -o arangodb -d /var/tmp/arangodb3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 654383 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -g arangodb -o arangodb -d /var/run/arangodb3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 654390 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/env chown -R arangodb:arangodb /var/log/arangodb3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 654391 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/env chmod 700 /var/log/arangodb3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 654392 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/env chown -R arangodb:arangodb /var/lib/arangodb3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 654393 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/env chmod 700 /var/lib/arangodb3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 654394 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/env chown -R arangodb:arangodb /var/lib/arangodb3-apps (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 654395 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/env chmod 700 /var/lib/arangodb3-apps (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 654396 (arangod)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 131072)
     Memory: 1.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/arangodb3.service

Jun 30 19:12:35 nkololo-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: Started ArangoDB database server.
Jun 30 19:12:35 nkololo-HP-Notebook arangod[654396]: 2023-06-30T17:12:35Z [654396] INFO [e52b0] {general} ArangoDB 3.11.1 [linux] 64bit, using jemalloc, build tags/v3.1>
Jun 30 19:12:35 nkololo-HP-Notebook arangod[654396]: 2023-06-30T17:12:35Z [654396] INFO [75ddc] {general} detected operating system: Linux version 5.4.0-152-generic (bu>
Jun 30 19:12:35 nkololo-HP-Notebook arangod[654396]: 2023-06-30T17:12:35Z [654396] INFO [25362] {memory} Available physical memory: 7240151040 bytes, available cores: 4
Jun 30 19:12:35 nkololo-HP-Notebook arangod[654396]: 2023-06-30T17:12:35Z [654396] INFO [a1c60] {syscall} file-descriptors (nofiles) hard limit is 131072, soft limit is>
Jun 30 19:12:35 nkololo-HP-Notebook arangod[654396]: 2023-06-30T17:12:35Z [654396] INFO [3bb7d] {cluster} Starting up with role SINGLE
Jun 30 19:12:35 nkololo-HP-Notebook arangod[654396]: 2023-06-30T17:12:35Z [654396] INFO [f6e0e] {aql} memory limit per AQL query automatically set to 4344090624 bytes. >
Jun 30 19:12:36 nkololo-HP-Notebook arangod[654396]: 2023-06-30T17:12:36Z [654396] FATAL [fe3df] {startup} unable to initialize RocksDB engine: Corruption: SST file is >
Jun 30 19:12:36 nkololo-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: arangodb3.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 30 19:12:36 nkololo-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: arangodb3.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 30 19:12:41 nkololo-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: arangodb3.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3540.
Jun 30 19:12:41 nkololo-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: Stopped ArangoDB database server.
Jun 30 19:12:41 nkololo-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: Starting ArangoDB database server...
Jun 30 19:12:42 nkololo-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: Started ArangoDB database server.
Jun 30 19:12:42 nkololo-HP-Notebook arangod[654575]: 2023-06-30T17:12:42Z [654575] INFO [e52b0] {general} ArangoDB 3.11.1 [linux] 64bit, using jemalloc, build tags/v3.1>
Jun 30 19:12:42 nkololo-HP-Notebook arangod[654575]: 2023-06-30T17:12:42Z [654575] INFO [75ddc] {general} detected operating system: Linux version 5.4.0-152-generic (bu>
Jun 30 19:12:42 nkololo-HP-Notebook arangod[654575]: 2023-06-30T17:12:42Z [654575] INFO [25362] {memory} Available physical memory: 7240151040 bytes, available cores: 4
Jun 30 19:12:42 nkololo-HP-Notebook arangod[654575]: 2023-06-30T17:12:42Z [654575] INFO [a1c60] {syscall} file-descriptors (nofiles) hard limit is 131072, soft limit is>
Jun 30 19:12:42 nkololo-HP-Notebook arangod[654575]: 2023-06-30T17:12:42Z [654575] INFO [3bb7d] {cluster} Starting up with role SINGLE
Jun 30 19:12:42 nkololo-HP-Notebook arangod[654575]: 2023-06-30T17:12:42Z [654575] INFO [f6e0e] {aql} memory limit per AQL query automatically set to 4344090624 bytes. >
Jun 30 19:12:43 nkololo-HP-Notebook arangod[654575]: 2023-06-30T17:12:43Z [654575] FATAL [fe3df] {startup} unable to initialize RocksDB engine: Corruption: SST file is >



```
````